# jQuery Ajax function not working on webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a project in which I'm changing displayed data using jQuery. jQuery function calls controller which returns result and changes data accordingly. This is working on Firefox but not on webkit browsers. Code is as follow:

```
    function PageMethod(fn, paramArray, successFn, errorFn, strdt, ty) {

        var dt;
        var ct;
        var typ;
        if (ty != '' && typeof (ty) != 'undefined') {
            typ = ty;
        } else {
            typ = "post";
        }
        if (strdt != '' && typeof (strdt) != 'undefined') {
            dt = strdt;
            ct = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
        } else {
            dt = 'json';
            ct = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }
        var paramList = '';
        if (paramArray.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < paramArray.length; i += 2) {
                if (paramList.length > 0) paramList += ',';
                paramList += '"' + paramArray[i] + '":"' + paramArray[i + 1] + '"';
            }
        }
        paramList = '{' + paramList + '}';

        $.ajax({
            type: typ,
            url: fn,
            contentType: ct,
            data: paramList,
            dataType: dt,
            success: successFn,
            error: errorFn
        });

    }

$("#btn").on('click', function (e) {
  call();
}
function(){
PageMethod(basedir + "userjoined",
            call_s,
            AjaxFailed);
}
function call_s(r){
 $("#div").html("<span>" +r + " </span>");
}
```

It is working on Firefox but not on other browsers. Please help.

Comment: do not set `contentType`, it is an Intelligent Guess. set the header of the file you are calling explicitly to `json`, and it will be bulletproof. also, please describe **how** it is not working, not just that it is not working.

Comment: Why is the call to `PageMethod()` at the bottom wrapped in an anonymous function? And the `$("#btn").on('click', ...` is not closed properly, where is the `);`?